# Typescript or ESLint rule to disallow default returns (in lambdas)?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I came across this error in my code and I felt it should have been picked up by Lint or Typescript itself. Is there is a plugin / additional setting I can set to make "default return" a compile warning?

What I wrote:

```
activeRegion = regions.find( region => { region.countryCode === activeCountryCode } )
```

What I should have written:

```
activeRegion = regions.find( region =>  region.countryCode === activeCountryCode  )
```

The second does what you want, and returns the region where the condition is true.

The first, because you have actually written a function, expects a return. BUT because JS has a concept of default returns, what it actually becomes is this

```
activeRegion = regions.find( region => { 
   region.countryCode === activeCountryCode
   return undefined;
 } )
```

which of course is nonsense in this case (nothing will be found), so is there a lint rule that would stop these sneaky default returns from getting added in?

Comment: This one would cover your case: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/array-callback-return, but it's only for methods of `Array`

Comment: Actually it also triggers this one https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.13.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions.md, because `{ region.countryCode === activeCountryCode }` is an assignment to a `bool` that is not used.

Comment: So I need to change the es lint config to have array-callback-return to true? That sounds perfect! You should post it as an answer :)

Comment: There is a config option [`noImplicitReturns`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitReturns) which you can enable in `tsconfig.json` ─ this will apply to all functions, not just lambdas. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules [`array-callback-return`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/array-callback-return) and [`no-unused-expressions`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-expressions) will both be triggered by this code.

To manually add a rule, here's how to do it, from the [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/rules#using-configuration-files):

In `.eslintrc.js`:

```
{
    ...
    "rules": {
        "array-callback-return": "error",
        "no-unused-expressions": "error",
    }
}
```

Or in yaml:

```
rules:
  array-callback-return: error
  no-unused-expressions: error
```

An easier way to to work with eslint is by using plugins, or extending a base configuration.
This adds a set of rules, without having to add them one by one.

For example in `.eslintrc.js`:

```
  ...
  extends: ["airbnb-typescript", ... ],
```

or

```
  ...
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", ...],
```

Two commonly used are the one from [Airbnb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb), and the [Typescript plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin) but there are more.
Note that you need to install the package before adding it to the eslint configuration.

More information in the [eslint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/).

Comment: we currently have 
extends: ['eslint:recommended'],
would you say the other two are much better?

Comment: If you're using Typescript, I would say `@typescript-eslint/recommended` is also probably a good idea. For the other two, we're pretty happy with them, only had to overwrite around 5 rules to adjust to our liking.